# Jenkins environment variables picking up stray commas, how do I prevent this?

Tags: windows, batch-file, variables, jenkins, environment

I have a problem with using jenkins environment variables. I am writing a batch file that can be called when a build is run that will write a file into the build directory with info about how the files were generated. (branch, date time, git revision, etc.)

The batch file just takes in some of the jenkins environment vars via command line parameters, and writes them to a text file. Here is the batch call I make via the Execute Shell step during build:

```
c:\\temp\\~BuildStamper.bat "$GIT_COMMIT", "$BUILD_URL", "$JOB_NAME",  "$BUILD_ID", "$WORKSPACE", "$GIT_BRANCH", "$BUILD_USER"
```

I have noticed that for arguments that contain white space, an extra comma is being appended inside the quoted delimiters. Sample line from generated text file:

Job Name: "Departure Board Build and Publish,"

I know that it isn't a problem with the processing I am doing inside the batch file, because I can see the values that are passed into the batch file in the job logs Jenkins generates, and the commas exist in the values when they are passed to my batch file.

It almost looks like Jenkins is incorrectly splitting a comma delimited string when it encounters strings with white space, but I couldn't find anything on the net about a problem with Jenkins of that nature.

Anyone else seen this? Am I doing something wrong? I tried passing the vars to Jenkins sans quotes, but then the batch file starts reading each word as a separate argument.

Comment: You don't need to explicitly add commas to something you invoke from a command shell.

Comment: blerg. You are totally correct, I don't know why I missed that before. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KeepCalmAndCarryOn nailed it, commas are totally extraneous.